# How do you make sure no two items have the same ID in an Array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array that stores the ID and Placeholder title of a new component every time the button "Create a list" is clicked. I am trying to make sure that there are no duplicated ID's. Essentially I just want check that the ID doesn't already exist, and if it does; to create a new one.

My code is below:

**ElementContext.js:**

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import Todobox from './components/Todobox';

export const ElementContext = createContext();

export const ElementContextProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);
    const [elementId, setElementId] = useState(1);

    const newElementId = (elements) =>{
        const newId = Math.floor(Math.random()*100).toString();
        setElementId(newId)
    }

    const newElement = () =>{
        newElementId();
        setElements((prev) => [...prev, {title: 'Placeholder', id:elementId}])
        console.log(elements)
    };

    const value = {
        elements,
        setElements,
        newElement,
        newElementId,
        elementId
    };

    return(
        <ElementContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </ElementContext.Provider>
    )
};
```

**HomePage.jsx:**

```
import react from 'react';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import Todobox from './Todobox';
import { ElementContext } from '../ElementContext';

export default function HomePage(){
    const { elements, setElements, newElement, elementsId } = useContext(ElementContext);


    return(
        <div className='page-container'>
        <div className='header'>
          <a className='header-title'>Trello Clone!</a>
          <a className='header-button' onClick={newElement}>Create a list</a>
        </div>
      <div className='element-field'>
        {elements.length !== 0 &&
          elements.map((elements, newElementId) => <Todobox key={newElementId} />)}
      </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Idea:

You need to implement a state that holds an object `const [refDict, setRefDict] = useState({});` that stores the key as `elementId` and value as `true`. So when you want to insert a new element need to check whether the state already has this key or not. if the state has the key it means `elementId` is not unique so no need to push to `setElements()` and vice versa.

Declare a new state as:

```
const [refDict, setRefDict] = useState({});
```

and inside your `newElement()` add logics like this:

```
const newElement = () => {
  newElementId();
  if (!refDict[elementId]) { //so if nothing in "refDict" that means the elementId is unique
    setElements(prev => [...prev, { title: 'Placeholder', id: elementId }]);
    setRefDict((prev) => ({...prev, [elementId]: true}));
  }
  console.log(elements);
};
```

You can also play around with this [sandbox](https://playcode.io/1006408)

Answer (score 0):

you need increments your array

```
setElementId(elementId + 1)
```

you only need this. more then this, is not necessary.
but, filter is one option.